# SFMC XML data extract - input file name wildcards

Tags: marketing-cloud, xml, data-extract

We are using an automation that is triggered by a file drop on the FTP. In this automation there is a Convert XML Data Extract Activity to convert the dropped XML file to a CSV file which can be imported into a DE. We are running into an issue regarding the naming of the input file that's on the FTP, can anyone confirm that wildcards like %%MONTH%% (or even better %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%) do not work here? Attached a screenshot of the configuration screen, seems strange that wildcards are available for the name of the output file but not for the input.

Perhaps to ask the question more broadly, is there a better way to deal with XML files than this extract activity?

Thanks!

[image]